# C++ Conditional template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, sfinae, enable-if

I have a `HandleID` class that acts similar to a smart pointer. Here are the important bits:

```cpp
template<class T>
class HandleID
{
// Only if T is not const
friend class HandleID<const T>;

public:
    HandleID();
    HandleID(int id);
    HandleID(const HandleID<T>& other);
    HandleID& operator=(const HandleID<T>& other);

    // Only if T is const
    HandleID(const HandleID<const removed T>& other);
    HandleID& operator=(const HandleID<const removed T>& other);


private:
    T* cachedPointer;
    int id;
};
```

Now I want to be able to construct a `HandleID<const T>` from a `HandleID<T>` but not the other way around. The same for the copy assignment operator: `HandleID<const T> = HandleID<T>` should be legal but not `HandleID<T> = HandleID<const T>`.

Now I thought about adding a template specialization or something for this but I'm sure there is a nicer way of doing this. Note that the non-const version must add the const version as a friend for it to be able to access the private members in the constructor / assignmnent operator.

Comment: [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) may work, but you could also simply specialize the template for const parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SFINAE way...

To simplify, you can add a `using` type for the no-const `T`

```
using no_const_T = std::remove_const_t<T>;
```

that is equal to `T` when `T` isn't `const`, different when `T` is `const`.

Then you can SFINAE enable your constructor/operator only when `T` and `no_const_T` are different

```
template <typename U = T,
          std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same_v<U, no_const_T>, int> = 0>
HandleID(const HandleID<no_const_T> & other);

template <int..., typename U = T, 
          std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same_v<U, no_const_T>, int> = 0>
HandleID& operator=(const HandleID<no_const_T>& other);
```

Observe that you have to check that `T` is equal or different to `no_const_T` not using directly `T` but a local (to the method) template parameter (`U`) that is initialized with `T`.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> what is the syntax when I want to separate the declaration (The one you provided) and the implementation (e.g. outside the class further down in the file)

It's a delirium.

The following is a full compiling (silly) example whit SFINAE enabled method implemented outside the body of the class.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class HandleID
 {
   friend class HandleID<T const>;

   using no_const_T = std::remove_const_t<T>;

   public:
      HandleID () {}
      HandleID (int) {}
      HandleID (HandleID<T> const &) {}

      template <typename U = T,
                std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same_v<U, no_const_T>, int> = 0>
      HandleID (HandleID<no_const_T> const &);

      HandleID & operator= (HandleID<T> &)
       { return *this; }

      template <int..., typename U = T,
                std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same_v<U, no_const_T>, int> = 0>
      HandleID & operator= (HandleID<no_const_T> const &);
 };

template <typename T>
template <typename U,
          std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same_v<U,
             std::remove_const_t<T>>, int>>
HandleID<T>::HandleID (HandleID<std::remove_const_t<T>> const &)
 { }

template <typename T>
template <int..., typename U,
          std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same_v<U,
             std::remove_const_t<T>>, int>>
HandleID<T> & HandleID<T>::operator=
   (HandleID<std::remove_const_t<T>> const &)
 { return *this; }

int main()
 {
   HandleID<int>       id0;
   HandleID<int const> idc0;

   HandleID<int>  id1{id0};  // copy constructor: compile
   //HandleID<int>  id2{idc0}; // constructor disabled: compilatrion error

   HandleID<int const>  idc1{idc0};  // copy constructor: compile
   HandleID<int const>  idc2{id0};   // constructor enabled: compile
 }
```

Comment: That is smart, I like it! For the friend class, I guess adding itself as a friend shouldn't be a problem right? Also, what's the syntax in the template implementation, would it be:

`template <int..., typename U = T, 
          std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same_v<U, HandleID<T>::no_const_T>, int> = 0>
HandleID<T>& operator=(const HandleID<no_const_T>& other);`

Or do I have to add another template<class T> infront of it

Comment: @AdrianAlbertKoch - For the itself friendness: exactly, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: For the exact syntax... give me some minutes and I try to add a full example.

Comment: I meant, what is the syntax when I want to separate the declaration (The one you provided) and the implementation (e.g. outside the class further down in the file). Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: @AdrianAlbertKoch - OK: I try to make the full example that way.

Comment: @AdrianAlbertKoch - Added a full example; take in count that compile with clang++ and not with my g++; I suspect a g++ bug but I'm not sure. How you can see, it's a delirium; suggestion: avoid separate implementation, when possible.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It compiles fine with clang++ but not with either MSVC or g++ :) Interesting. I'll let you know if I find out why

Comment: One last question: The copy constructor makes perfect sense to me, we use enable_if and provide a default = 0 to hide it. The only thing I don't get is why the int..., is necessary  in the copy assignment operator

Comment: @AdrianAlbertKoch - The `int...` for the operator isn't strictly necessary. I've added it to prevent that a user enable it, when should be disabled, explicating the `U`. Adding a variadic template parameter before, prevent this possibility. This isn't necessary for the constructor because it's impossible (as far I know) explicit a template parameter for a template constructor.

Comment: @AdrianAlbertKoch - Found a way to compile with both g++ and clang++. The trick is use, in the external implementation, `HandleID<std::remove_const_t<T>>` instead of `typename HandleID<T>::no_const_T>`. Maybe I'll add a question to ask if is right g++ or clang++.

Answer (score 1):

In C++20, it would be:

```
template<class T>
class HandleID
{
friend class HandleID<const T>;

public:
    HandleID();
    HandleID(int id);
    HandleID(const HandleID<T>& other);
    HandleID& operator=(const HandleID<T>& other);

    HandleID(const HandleID<std::remove_const_t<T>>& other) requires (std::is_const_v<T>);
    HandleID& operator=(const HandleID<std::remove_const_t<T>>& other) requires (std::is_const_v<T>);

private:
    T* cachedPointer;
    int id;
};
```